# Implementation with same method declared twice

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm going through a book on iOS programming and came across something a bit confusing.

From what I've learned so far, methods in the implementation go like this

```
- (return type)methodName: (return type)parameter methodName2:(return type)parameter
```

But why would you have an implementation for the same method twice? Like this:

```
- (return type)methodName: (return type)parameter methodName2:(return type)parameter
{
// Code here
}
- (return type)methodName: (return type)parameter methodName3:(return type)parameter {
// Code here
}
```

Does this just mean there are two declarations that use the same method name, but it knows which to implement based on all the methods in the implementation? I was under the impression the first method name was "the method" and the rest were arguments of that method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different methods here, and they are named

```
methodName:methodName2:
```

and

```
methodName:methodName3:
```

In objective-c, the "full method name" is spread across all arguments.

Comment: Thanks! A bit confusing coming from PHP but that cleared things up.

Comment: I agree :) If you use Xcode, you'll see how it is parsed if you mouse-over and hold down cmd (or whichever key is it), and it will underline the parts that make up the method name.